# Mind ya, it's Homophones Everywhere!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

No gibberish, let's jump to the riddle!

> I am a NAME.
>   Remove a letter, I am what a name may stand for.
>   Remove yet another letter, I am another name of another type.
>   What on earth am I?

Oh, and just to remove this puzzle from the too-broad list, all the names *sound the same*.

Comment: Wow, just looked at this right before posting a homophone riddle which is the same thing as this :) +1!

Comment: great minds think alike :) @Duck

Comment: I think another of my homophone riddles is sole/soul. You could have done four (Sol, Seoul, sole, soul)!

Comment: ooh, but I'd rather stick to the removal of letters PLUS the homophones... that's what so special abt this ;) @Duck

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure this is the intended answer but:

> **Seoul**: the name of a city
>  **soul**: a person, what a name could stand for
>  **Sol**: the name of our sun

Comment: Hmm. I think you have it.

Comment: yep, nicely done!

Comment: Put the first letter back in in a different spot and it gets a bit fishy...

Comment: @Darrel What do you mean?? Sorry I'm stupid :P

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I think he means to make "sole" from sol + e, with the same homonym.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to be circumspect since there's no spoiler tags in comments and rot13 is annoying.  I could've also said "it stands alone", but I went for the fish-pun instead.